# Prefix vs. Postfix increment when no other operation is involved?

Tags: java, postfix-operator, prefix-operator

```
++i;
```

vs.

```
i++;
```

Does the use of prefix increment or the use of postfix increment make a difference in the given two statements (the point being that no other operation is involved there, except incrementing the variable)?

Comment: Now why did I get a downvote?

Comment: @TheProgrammerG Yeah, but then someone just upvoted it (thanks to that someone ;) ), making the net value of upvotes and downvotes zero, that's why no downvote or upvote is showing in the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. It just increment the value of i by one and that's it.

Answer (score 3):

The end result is exactly the same in both scenarios. The use of ++i and i++ makes no difference in that regard. However, there may be performance differences; although, these would be almost absolutely negligible.

Basically, ++i is guaranteed to be as fast as i++; however, i++ is not guaranteed to be as fast as ++i. So, if you do not need the intermediate value [such as when ++i or i++ is a single statement], then prefer ++i. Most common compilers may optimize this difference out, but the specification is clear about the different behaviors and guarantees. In other words, i++ may do one additional unnecessary step.

`// The compiler turns i++ into the following
int temp = i;
i = i + 1;
return temp;`

Versus:

`// The compiler turns ++i into the following
i = i + 1;
return i;`

For a detailed reference about this, see http://fairwaytech.com/2012/03/prefix-vs-postfix-increment-and-decrement-operators-in-c/